# "main" java.lang.error not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, methods, compilation, arguments

How exactly would I fix this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method methodName(className[], String, int) in the type Program is not applicable for the arguments ()

    at Program.main(Program.java:43)
```

A snippet of my code, calling the method:

```
public class Program {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    methodName();
  }
}
```

methodName code:

```
public static void methodName(className[] array, String stringName, int counter){
 //Code here
}
```

Comment: you have no arguments passed to your method methodName()

Comment: Do I have to pass the className[], stringName, and counter?

Comment: If either of the answers below have helped you, please consider accepting it. This will give both you and the answerer a small amount of reputation, and will indicate to others that you have found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the parameter's as needed by methodName which you are not passing now.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `methodName` as taking 3 arguments, which means that whenever you call it, you have to pass it three arguments or else you will get this error. The reason is that the method name along with the list of arguments and their type constitute what is called the method signature, which uniquely identifies a method.

If you try to call `methodName()` without passing the arguments, you're essentially asking for a different method signature, in this case one that doesn't exist, which is what's going wrong. There are two ways to solve this:

**Implement `methodName()`**

You could write a definition for `methodName()` with no arguments at all like this:

```
public static void methodName()
{
    // Code that does not require any parameters
}
```

And then when you call `methodName()` you will get the code you have written here.

**Call `methodName(arg1, arg2, arg3)`**

If you actually pass `methodName` all three arguments, you'll get the code that you've labeled "//Code here". Be sure also that you don't just pass three arguments of any type, but specifically

```
className[] arg1;
String arg2;
int counter;

// Initialize the values to whatever you want

methodName(arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

And that will run as you expect.